# Other session in PHP application

Tags: php, .htaccess, session, web, php-ini

I have a strange problem with the session...
I created the MVC php app with redirection in htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/Public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /Public/$1 [L]
```

and htaccess in Public dir:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

In default api index.php (url: domain.com/offer or domain.com/gallery) session work normally

```
<?php print_r($_SESSION); ?>
//result: ARRAY ( [TEST] => TRUE )

<?=session_id()?>
//result: 6a5d103581340500d75b76c47f335d4e
```

BUT! if i use a url: domain.com/ajaxFilePHP/signIn.php
session doesn't work correctly...

```
<?php print_r($_SESSION); ?>
//result: Array( [IL] => 1 [NAME] => admin [LID] => 1 )

<?=session_id()?>
//result:
```

I checked that the ajax and client connection is the same.

Its not my server... in my PC and in my server, api work correctly... session configuration in php ini is almost identical...

My server:

```
Cookie - PHPSESSID=....
HTTP_COOKIE - PHPSESSID=...

session.cookie_httponly - no value
session.gc_divisor  - 1000
session.sid_bits_per_character - 5
session.sid_length - 26
```

other server:

```
Cookie - no entry in ini
HTTP_COOKIE - no entry in ini

session.cookie_httponly - 0
session.gc_divisor  - 100
session.sid_bits_per_character - 4
session.sid_length - 32
```

someone can help?

EDIT:
I have session_start(); in every file in ajaxFilePHP dir

```
<?php 
session_start();
require_once realpath(dirname(__FILE__)."/../../App/Core/DataBase/DBinit.php");
if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['pass'])){
    $l = new LoginDB();
    exit($l->Login($_POST['name'], $_POST['pass']));
}
exit('100');
```

EDIT2:

Main file:

```
session_status();
//return code: 2
```

ajaxPhpFile:

```
session_status();
//return code: 1
```

Comment: There is no error checking in any of the code. You have not told us if error logging is enabled nor what is in the logs. You have not told us if the cookie config missing from the above is using the defaults. You've not told us what the response headers defining the cookies are. You've only told us it is "not working correctly" - and we don't know what that means.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use php session make sure that your file which need php session, you need add on top: `session_start();` otherwise you wont get any results from session array, good practice would be if you have common header.php like for example add on top `session_start();`

Comment: i have session_start(); in main php file and in every file in /ajaxFilePHP/

Comment: Did you try to check if session is on? like echo session_status(); also it could be that your session cookie got short lifetime period

Comment: session_status() return code 2 in main.
session_status() return code 1 in ajaxPhpFile

Comment: It means your session is not started or it could be that there is some checks in your code which block session_start();

Comment: No, because it would output session_status() =  0, your code outputs 1, which means session_start is missing or session cookie time is too short or somewhere you have session_regenerate_id which also mess with your session settings

Comment: Ok, i checked:
session_start working (`function_exists("session_start")` returned true);
cookies time 1440 <- default value, should be correct;
session_regenerate_id <- nowhere is entered in the code. when I tried to use it, no changes in the behavior of the application

Comment: Can you post your ajaxFilePHP?

Comment: I dnt know why it doesn't work, but when I use exceptions, it works without a problem. I dnt use files outside the application and everything is fine.